# Merge [gollum] and [smeagol]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

For some completely unfathomable reason, we appear to have two tags for this character: [gollum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gollum) and [smeagol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smeagol). Can we please merge these?

Comment: Gah. Spoilers!!!

Comment: There were only 2 questions tagged [tag:smeagol]; it would have been easy to retag them manually. Nevertheless, *BOOM*.

Comment: @Rand ah, but then there would not be a synonym...

Comment: ... and throw them both down a volcano because they are character tags? :)

Comment: I'm totally late to this party, but Smeagol and Gollum seem like two separate characters to me. While Smeagol's possession of the One Ring kind of separates him from what he becomes -- Gollum -- I do note that it took Smeagol many years to turn into Gollum and forget himself as ever having been Smeagol. Just commenting.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the tag [clark-kent] is a synonym of [superman]; [tom-riddle] is a synonym of [voldemort]; but [anakin-skywalker] is not a synonym of [darth-vader] but both those have a lot of questions.

Comment: @b_jonas so maybe it's time to merge them :)

Comment: See also http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/843/4918 "Star-Wars character tags" about [darth-vader] vs [anakin-skywalker], as well as various tags for the Emperor Palpatine.

Comment: @Mithrandir - merge them! There's such a thing as TOO much CDO,

Comment: Suggest [Smeagol, Gollum video from Colbert show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nweyH1uLcV8), it is funny if nothing. And a possible argument for @Slytherincess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Make [gollum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gollum) the main tag and make [smeagol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smeagol) a synonym.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant :)